# Excel VBA table: Does anyone know how to do this?

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know how to change this from [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trw3U.png) to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k3uf.png). I mean the first 4 rows so it's matching the if statements in code above and it's working so with all data . I modified code from an answer to another question of mine. I understand the answer code that I modified, but now I'm stuck and don't know what to do with it. I tried the `i=i+1` but it overwrites values.

```vb
Sub testo()

    Const cSheet As String = "Procenty"   
    Const cRange As String = "A2:D73"     
    Const cel As Long = 4             
    Const cCol As Variant = "A"           

    Dim vntS As Variant   
    Dim vntT As Variant   
    Dim i As Integer     
    Dim emptyRow As Long  
    Dim kom As Double, komz As Double, kredyt As Double
    Dim roz As Double, komr As Double, komn As Double 
    Dim dz As Date, dw As Date 

    vntS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cRange)

    ReDim vntT(1 To UBound(vntS), 1 To cel)

    kredyt = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)
        If vntS(i, 1) = "" Then
            dw = Date
        Else
            dz = vntS(i, 1)
        End If

        dz = vntS(i, 1)
        komz = vntS(i, 2)
        dw = vntS(i, 3)
        kom = vntS(i, 4)

        If kom = komz Then

            vntT(i, 1) = dz
            vntT(i, 2) = komz
            vntT(i, 3) = dw
            vntT(i, 4) = kom

        ElseIf komz > kom Then
            komr = komz - kom
            vntT(i, 1) = dz
            vntT(i, 2) = komz
            vntT(i, 3) = dw
            vntT(i, 4) = kom
            vntT(i + 1, 1) = dz
            vntT(i + 1, 2) = komr
            vntT(i + 1, 3) = dw
            vntT(i + 1, 4) = kom

        ElseIf komz < kom Then
            komn = kom - komz
            vntT(i, 1) = dz
            vntT(i, 2) = komz
            vntT(i, 3) = dw
            vntT(i, 4) = kom
            vntT(i + 1, 3) = dw
            vntT(i + 1, 4) = komn

        End If

    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)

        emptyRow = .Columns(cCol).Find("*", , xlFormulas, _
        xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row + 1
'emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(cCol)) + 1
' wypisywanie tablicy
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol).Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2)) = vntT
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol) = kredyt
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What's this supposed to do?  What is the "this" in the title? At the start of the loop you have an If block for setting dw/dz but then immediately set them again without any test?  Also your code will crash when you try to access the `i+1` element if `i` is at the loop limit...

Comment: With "this" I meant changing it to work as in the screenshots, at the start the if block is setting values iif the cell is empty, I know that it will crash.

Comment: Sorry that's a little too much like "spot the difference", and I can't use your code as a guide given it doesn't really work - do you need a separate counter for filling `vntT` as it looks like you're adding additional rows?

Comment: Please for the love of all things code, nice. neat formatting of code is essential for not only you, but us too...

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess...

```
Sub testo()

    Const cSheet As String = "Procenty"
    Const cRange As String = "A2:D73"
    Const cel As Long = 4
    Const cCol As Variant = "A"

    Dim vntS As Variant
    Dim vntT As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    Dim kom As Double, komz As Double, kredyt As Double
    Dim roz As Double, komr As Double, komn As Double
    Dim dz As Date, dw As Date

    vntS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cRange).Value

    ReDim vntT(1 To 2 * UBound(vntS), 1 To cel) '<< add space for extra rows

    kredyt = 0
    r = 1 '<< "row" counter for vntT
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)

        dz = vntS(i, 1)
        komz = vntS(i, 2)
        dw = vntS(i, 3)
        kom = vntS(i, 4)

        vntT(r, 1) = dz
        vntT(r, 2) = komz
        vntT(r, 3) = dw
        vntT(r, 4) = kom
        r = r + 1

        If komz > kom Then
            komr = komz - kom
            vntT(r, 1) = dz
            vntT(r, 2) = komr
            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = kom
            r = r + 1
        ElseIf komz < kom Then
            komn = kom - komz
            vntT(r, 3) = dw
            vntT(r, 4) = komn
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next

    'etc...

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry but could you explain this, and also i get type mismatch on dz=vntS(i,1)

Comment: I didn't add that line, but it seems like your expected data type is not what's in the array at that slot.  Exactly which part do you want me to explain?

Comment: Now I got rid off the problem the vaules were like out of range,and now I posted more precise question to my problem using code you provided, because this one wasn't everything I wanted to do. If you could help me with it I would be very greatful :)